# Count number of strings that match in two arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, match

Given two Strings arrays, a and b, each in alphabetical order, I want to return the count of the number of strings that match in both arrays.

```
public int countMatch(String[] a, String[] b) {

}
```

My aim is to be able to call the method as follows;

```
countMatch({"apple", "banana", "xylophone"}, {"banana", "carrot", "dog", "xray", "xylophone"});
```

which should return the int value 2, as there are two strings that match each array ("banana" and "xylophone").

It may be important to note that the arrays will both always be in alphabetical order, if that helps with the solution.

Comment: Can you have the same string in the same array more than once?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, the same string can be in each array more than once.

Comment: What should be the count for `{"apple", "apple", "apple"}`and `{"apple", "apple"}`?

Comment: The count for the example you gave would be 2

Comment: How did you come up with `2`?

Comment: As we iterate through each array, we only want to identify strings that match, and as there are only 2 strings in the second array, of which both contain "Apple", we can only find 2 matching Strings in the first array.

Comment: Do you want it to count how many matches it found in the arrays?

Comment: Yes @TatakaiWasumi, that is the goal

Comment: never mind yes you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code is below:

```
public class Test {

public static int findMatchCount(final String [] a,final String [] b){
    int matchCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0, j = 0;i < a.length && j < b.length;){
        int res = a[i].compareTo(b[j]);
        if(res == 0){
            matchCount++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }else if(res < 0){
            i++;
        }else{
            j++;
        }
    }
    return matchCount;
}

public static void main(String[] args){ 
    String[] a = {"apple", "apple"};
    String[] b = {"apple", "apple"};
    System.out.println(findMatchCount(a,b));

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As soon as these arrays are sorted you could do as follows:

You'll have two variables: `i` and `j`. First will walk through first array and second through second.

Then you compare `a[i]` and `b[j]`. 
If they are equal it's a match and you advance both indices. 
If they are not equal advance index which is at word which is less (if `a[i] < b[j]` advance `i` else `j`).

Comment: as I said, I am a newbie to Java, so this seems a little complex! Could you expand more with the actual code?

Comment: I think the idea is that you try for yourself as opposed to someone else writing code for you. Maybe start with a simple case.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple method like :

```
public int countMatch(String[] a, String[] b) {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a));
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(b);
    list1.retainAll(list2);
    return list1.size();
}
```

Comment: Nice.  How does this work when values are repeated, e.g. ["apple", "apple"]?

Comment: You can look at the source code of retainAll() method. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java

Answer (score 2):

You can compare those arrays using a `for` loop and comparing the first index of first array to all second array indexes and continuing to the others first array indexes. Like this:

```
public class Ber {
    public static void main( String[] arg){

       String[] abc1 = {"1", "7", "j", "kolo", "7", "1"};
       String[] abc2 = {"2", "n", "m", "2", "n", "kolo"};

       for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < abc2.length; i++) {
          if (abc1[i].equals(abc2[j])){
            System.out.println("found first index: "+i+" second index: "+j);
            break;
          } else if (i == abc1.length-1) {
            i = 0;
            j++;
          } 

          System.out.println("searching... "+i+" "+j);
      }
   }
}
```

And you could see something like this:

```
searching... 0 0
searching... 1 0
searching... 2 0
searching... 3 0
searching... 4 0
searching... 0 1
searching... 1 1
searching... 2 1
searching... 3 1
searching... 4 1
searching... 0 2
searching... 1 2
searching... 2 2
searching... 3 2
searching... 4 2
searching... 0 3
searching... 1 3
searching... 2 3
searching... 3 3
searching... 4 3
searching... 0 4
searching... 1 4
searching... 2 4
searching... 3 4
searching... 4 4
searching... 0 5
searching... 1 5
searching... 2 5
found first index: 3 second index: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public final class StringArrayMatcher{

    public int findMatchCount(final String [] a,final String [] b){
        /*
            If a has more than one entries that matches to a string in b, it's also considered as accountable.
        */
            int matchCount = 0;

            for(String x_element : a){
                for(String y_element : b){
                    if(x_element.equals(y_element)) ++matchCount;                       
                }
            }
            return matchCount;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.format("Total matches = %d",new StringArrayMatcher().findMatchCount(new String[]{"apple", "banana", "xylophone"}, new String[]{"banana", "carrot", "dog", "xray", "xylophone"}));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's simply not cool to post the solution here. The OP hasn't made the slightest effort to solve the problem himself.

Comment: I think this solution is wrong.When the two strings are {"apple", "apple"} and  {"apple","apple"}. This will return four. However the right answer is two.

Comment: Yeah. You are right Jan. Sorry. Won't do this any more. Let him study.

Answer (score 0):

Unless ultimate performance is an issue, ignore the fact that they are sorted.  Put all the values from a[] into a HashSet.  Loop over b[] and count how many are contained in the Set.

Comment: Would you be able to share the code to make this happen? I am very new to Java and am trying to understand how to do this.

Comment: @Hugo My typical consultant rate is over $100 an hour.  :-). More seriously, you need two loops and call `myHashSet.contains().`

Comment: I think you are also wrong. When the two strings are {"apple", "apple"} and {"apple","apple"}. This will return one. However the right answer is two.

Comment: @uttp If you loop over both values of b[ ], each will be contained and the answer will be 2.  Only the values in a[ ] get put into a Set.  However, if you try to get "too clever" I can imagine times where the answer would be one.

Comment: @user949300 Ok , I konw your meaning. `a = {"apple"} and b = {"apple", "apple"}`. Your solution will return two, however the right answer is one.

Comment: I have no idea what the correct answer is for that case.  Doubt if OP does either.  Two of b match a, but only one in a matches b.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count two matching words exactly once, regardless of their occurrence, as you said; try this code

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public final class StringArrayMatcher{

    public int findMatchCount(final String [] a,final String [] b){

        int matchCount = 0;

        Set<String> setA = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
        List<String> setB = Arrays.asList(b);

        for(String value1 : setA){
            for(String value2 : setB){
                if(value1.equals(value2)){ ++matchCount; break; }
            }
        }
            return matchCount;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.format("Total matches = %d",new StringArrayMatcher().findMatchCount(new String[]{"apple"}, new String[]{"apple","apple"}));
    }
}
```

*The use of Set automatically prunes duplicate words from the array.

Comment: May be your answer is wrong. {"apple", "apple", "apple"}and {"apple", "apple"} will get 2, but your solution will get 1.

Comment: So you don't wanna prune the duplicate values in the second array ? Okay, just change this piece of code for setB as List<String> setB = Arrays.asList(b);. Try this.

Comment: your  change solution will also be wrong. if  `a={"apple"} and b= {"apple", "apple"}` , you solution will be 2. However the right solution will be 1.

Comment: I'd updated the code. As you suggest, you wanna see each entry in the second array as distinct, regardless of whether they are equal or not right ? So what the trick is if you find a matching entry in the second array, then don't proceed further, and return the control back to the first array iteration. Check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

If you totally do not care about the alphabetic order. Then it is simple, you need two loops to finish the job, i.e., you need to compare all possible pairs. in your example, you need 3*5 comparisons to conclude.

```
public int countMatch(String[] a, String[] b) {

        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<b.length; i++){
                if(a[i].equals(b[i])){
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

However, if considering the alphabetic order, it can be simply improved.

```
public int countMatch1(String[] a, String[] b) {

        int count = 0;
        int cursor = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            for(int j=cursor; j<b.length; i++){
                if(a[i].equals(b[i])){
                    count++;
                    cursor = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

In this case, you can use a variable cursor to remember where you stopped for last search for array a[i], then for next search a[i+1], you can simply start from the cursor instead of starting over since all the previous ones before the cursor cannot match a[i+1] for sure.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do this using sets and lists. If you use java sooner or later you're gonna start using them anyways might as well start soon and later research on how they work.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
public final class Match{


    public int countMatch( String [] a, String [] b){
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
            set.retainAll(Arrays.asList(b));
            System.out.println("The number of matches is " + set.size());

            return set.hashCode();
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] a = {"apple", "banana", "xylophone"};
        String[] b = {"banana", "carrot", "dog", "xray", "xylophone"};

        Match countMatch = new Match();
        countMatch.countMatch(a, b);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function do the job for you which in this case it's job is count two matching words **exactly once**, regardless of their occurrence.

**Let's see how it works:**

It iterates over 2 arrays and only compare the last occurrence of iterated item in each array for not counting duplicates.
At the end for some optimization we skip checking first's array item with second array's items if it is smaller.

*This function only works when 2 arrays sorted alphabetically*.

```
public int commonTwo(String[] a, String[] b) {
  int c = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
      if(a.length - i >= 2 && a[i].equals(a[i+1])) break;
      if(b.length - j >= 2 && b[j].equals(b[j+1])) continue;
      int cmp = a[i].compareTo(b[j]);
      if(cmp == 0) {
          c++;
      } else if(cmp < 0){
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return c;
}
```

Samples:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] a = {"a", "c", "x"};
    String[] b = {"a", "b", "c", "x", "z"};

    int count = commonTwo(a, b);
    System.out.println(count); // prints 3

    String[] a2 = {"a", "a", "b", "b", "c"};
    String[] b2 = {"a", "b", "b", "b", "c"};

    int count = commonTwo(a2, b2);
    System.out.println(count); // prints 3

    }

}
```